# What is the default concrete type of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

(Sorry for the vague title; couldn't think of anything better. Feel free to rephrase.)

So let's say my function or property returns an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Adults
{
  get
  {
    return _Members.Where(i => i.Age >= 18);
  }
}
```

If I run a `foreach` on this property without actually materializing the returned enumerable:

```
foreach(var Adult in Adults)
{
  //...
}
```

Is there a rule that governs whether `IEnumerable<Person>` will be materialized to array or list or something else?

Also is it safe to cast `Adults` to `List<Person>` or Array without calling `ToList()` or `ToArray()`?

### Edit

Many people have spent a lot of effort into answering this question. Thanks to all of them. However, the gist of this question still remains unanswered. Let me put in some more details:

I understand that `foreach` doesn't require the target object to be an array or list. It doesn't even need to be a collection of any kind. All it needs the target object to do is to implement enumeration. However if I place inspect the value of target object, it reveals that the actual underlying object is `List<T>` (just like it shows `object (string)` when you inspect a boxed string object). This is where the confusion starts. Who performed this materialization? I inspected the underlying layers (`Where()` function's source) and it doesn't look like those functions are doing this.

So my problem lies at two levels.

- First one is purely theoretical. Unlike many other disciplines like physics and biology, in computer sciences we always know precisely how something works (answering @zzxyz's last comment); so I was trying to dig about the agent who created `List<T>` and how it decided it should choose a `List` and not an `Array` and if there is a way of influencing that decision from our code.
- My second reason was practical. Can I rely on the type of actual underlying object and cast it to `List<T>`? I need to use some `List<T>` functionality and I was wondering if for example `((List<Person>)Adults).BinarySearch()` is as safe as `Adults.ToList().BinarySearch()`?

I also understand that it isn't going to create any performance penalty even if I do call `ToList()` explicitly. I was just trying to understand how it is working. Anyway, thanks again for the time; I guess I have spent just too much time on it.

Comment: There is no concrete type, in general. Only guarantee is that IEnumerable is implemented. That is true both theoretically and practically. So no, not safe.

Comment: @zzxyz: But doesn't `foreach` require target collection to be force-materialized into something before the loop could actually run?

Comment: @dotNET - No, there is no such thing as "force-materialized". The interface doesn't have to be any specific type at all for it to work - that's the point of interfaces.

Comment: There is no default concrete type. It depends on the type for example, 'adults' is your case, and as it implements `IEnumerable` you can do a for...each on this.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Thanks. I understand your point that all `foreach` cares about for `Adults` collection is to implement `IEnumerable` whatever concrete type it be. The question I'm struggling with is who decides that concrete type in case we don't, just as I did above?

Comment: @dotNET - `Adults` doesn't even need to implement `IEnumerable`. The developer of the class or method decides what the concrete return type is.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Right. Now we're closer. So in this case, the developer is myself and you can see, I haven't used any concrete type for `Adults`. Do you mean it depends on the type of `_Members` now? If not, who in this case will decide the type of `Adults`?

Comment: @dotNET - You have used the `.Where` operator. You would need to check with the developer of the `.Where` operator as to what concrete class they used. It has nothing to do with `_Members` at that point.

Comment: When you start iterating Adults in the for each loop, the concrete type for Adults is what _Members is. Isn't it ?

Comment: @C.Dhruv: No. It isn't. Confusingly, it is actually `List<Person>`. I'm struggling to understand who decided this? `Where()` function as indicated by @Enigmativity should have returned `WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>`. See @Zohar's answer below and the comments.

Comment: @C.Dhruv: Ignore my last comment. It actually is the same type as `_Members`, i.e. `List<Person>`. But then again, according to @Enigmativity, it shouldn't have anything to do with the type of `_Members` (which I think is logical).

Answer (score 3):

In general terms all you need for a `foreach` to work is to have an object with an accessible `GetEnumerator()` method that returns an object that has the following methods:

```
void Reset()
bool MoveNext()
T Current { get; private set; } // where `T` is some type.
```

You don't even need an `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`.

This code works as the compiler figures out everything it needs:

```
void Main()
{
    foreach (var adult in new Adults())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(adult.ToString());
    }
}

public class Adult
{
    public override string ToString() => "Adult!";
}

public class Adults
{
    public class Enumerator
    {
        public Adult Current { get; private set; }
        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (this.Current == null)
            {
                this.Current = new Adult();
                return true;
            }
            this.Current = null;
            return false;
        }
        public void Reset() { this.Current = null; }
    }
    public Enumerator GetEnumerator() { return new Enumerator(); }
}
```

Having a proper enumerable makes the process work more easily and more robustly. The more idiomatic version of the above code is:

```
public class Adults
{
    private class Enumerator : IEnumerator<Adult>
    {
        public Adult Current { get; private set; }

        object IEnumerator.Current => this.Current;

        public void Dispose() { }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (this.Current == null)
            {
                this.Current = new Adult();
                return true;
            }
            this.Current = null;
            return false;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            this.Current = null;
        }
    }
    public IEnumerator<Adult> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new Enumerator();
    }
}
```

This enables the `Enumerator` to be a private class, i.e. `private class Enumerator`. The interface then does all of the hard work - it's not even possible to get a reference to the `Enumerator` class outside of `Adults`.

The point is that you **do not know at compile-time** what the concrete type of the class is - and if you did you may not even be able to cast to it.

The interface is all you need, and even that isn't strictly true if you consider my first example.

If you want a `List<Adult>` or an `Adult[]` you must call `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` respectively.

Comment: Trying to recreate this (idiomatic version) implementation for my own code gives me an error or two; the [first error set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfPrv.png) and [second error set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJwAQ.png) -- any idea why they might be complaining about those errors and how I could fix them? (errors shared as screenshots just to ensure they'd fit along w/ full code in the space of a comment--thought that might be clearer)

Comment: Oops--ignore the above; my class file did not include `using System.Collections;` ...leaving the above comment along w/ this one in case others find this and encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a *default concrete type* for any interface.
The entire point of an interface is to **guarantee** properties, methods, events or indexers, without the user need of any knowledge of the concrete type that implements it.

When using an interface, all you can know is the properties, methods, events and indexers this interface declares, and that's all you actually need to know. That's just another aspect of encapsulation - same as when you are using a method of a class you don't need to know the internal implementation of that method.

To answer your question in the comments:

> who decides that concrete type in case we don't, just as I did above?

That's the code that created the instance that's implementing the interface.
Since you can't do `var Adults = new IEnumerable<Person>` - it has to be a concrete type of some sort.

As far as I see in the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) for linq's Enumerable extensions - the `where` returns either an instance of `Iterator<TSource>` or an instance of `WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>`. I didn't bother checking further what exactly are those types, but I can pretty much guarantee they both implement `IEnumerable`, or the guys at Microsoft are using a different c# compiler then the rest of us... :-)

Comment: Thanks again. This answer addresses my actual confusion. One last thing I'm left with is that inspecting this variable during debugging reveals that the actual concrete type in this case is `List<T>`. Does that appear to make sense?

Comment: *Does that appear to make sense?* I guess so. I can't think of any reason why the debugger will show you the wrong type...

Comment: But according to what you have explained, shouldn't it be an instance of `Iterator<TSource>` or `WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>`?

Comment: That's what I saw in the source code I've linked to. Perhaps it's a different version, and perhaps I'm wrong... You can check the source code yourself and see.

Comment: The actual type of the enumerable depends on the source. If I use a `List<T>` as source, I get a `WhereListIterator<T>`, when using an array, I get `WhereArrayIterator<T>`. Getting a list seems a little bit strange to me.

Answer (score 2):

The following code hopefully highlights why neither you nor the compiler can assume an underlying collection:

```
public class OneThroughTen : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private static int bar = 0;
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return ++bar;
            if (bar == 10)
                { yield break; }
        }
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<int> x = new OneThroughTen();
        foreach (int i in x)
            { Console.Write("{0} ", i); }
    }
}
```

Output being, of course:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Note, the code above behaves extremely poorly in the debugger.  I don't know why.  This code behaves just fine:

```
public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
{
  while (bar < 10)
  {
    yield return ++bar;
  }
  bar = 0;
}
```

(I used `static` for `bar` to highlight that not only does the `OneThroughTen` not have a specific collection, it doesn't have **any** collection, and in fact has no instance data whatsoever.  We could just as easily return 10 random numbers, which would've been a better example, now that I think on it :))

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I understand exactly what you're saying. This has been highlighted by others too. Problem is that if I inspect `Adults` collection in the debugger, it tells me that the actual underlying object is `List<Person>`. This is the real question. Who decided this type and at which point? Is this in some way related to the fact that the original collection (`_Members`) is `List<Person>`?

Comment: Also note that Enigmativity (see comments under the question) believes that the actual underlying concrete type should be determined by `Where()` function and should not have any relation with the type of `_Members`. Looking at the source code of `Where()`, the function should create an object of `WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>` and not `List<T>`.

Comment: Yes, he is correct.  `IEnumerable<int> y = x.Where((o) => o == 5 || o == 6);`  It goes without saying that `x` and `y` are two entirely different objects or can be.  I thought you were asking about `x` during enumeration.  `y` is just...whatever happens to be returned by whatever function you are calling.  But again, you wouldn't ever want to make assumptions about what that is (beyond the declared return type, of course).

Comment: Maybe I'm somehow unable to clarify myself. I'm NOT contesting the fact that we can't rely on the return type of `y`. What I'm saying is that if you check the type of `y` during debugging (e.g. QuckWatch), it shows this: `IEnumerable<int> (List<int>)` (the same way that it says `object (string)` for boxed objects); meaning that the underlying concrete object happens to be `List<int>`. I'm just asking about that; who decided it and at which point?

Comment: I mean, my answer would be "whoever created the object" and "when they created it", but I think you already know that, so I'm guessing I still don't understand what you're driving at.

Comment: My answer was a bit lengthy, so I have added it in the original post (Edit section). Thanks for your time. Guess I have gone too far with this. :)

Answer (score 0):

From your edited question and comments it sounds like you understand the general concept of using IEnumerable, and that you cannot assume that "a list object backs all IEnumerable objects". Your real question is about something that has confused you in the debugger, but we've not really been able to understand exactly what it is you are seeing. Perhaps a screenshot would help?

Here I have 5 `IEnumerable<int>` variables which I assign in various ways, along with how the "Watch" window describes them. Does this show the confusion you are having? If not, can you construct a similarly short program and screenshot that does?

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rob. Nice effort. There you go. If you look at the watch window (first item, Type column), the debugger shows the concrete type of the actual object in curly braces for each `IEnumerable`. For example, even though the first variable `w` is an `Enumerable<int>`, the real concrete underlying object is `List<int>`, shown in braces. This makes perfect sense in your case, since you're actually creating a `List<int>` in your code. So far so good... (see next comment)...

Comment: OTOH, my code never creates a `List<Person>`. My property simply returns the result of `Where()` function without calling `ToArray()` or `ToList()` inside the property. The caller of the property then runs a foreach loop directly on the property, again without calling any explicit materialization function. Even so, when I put a watch on this property, the debugger shows it like `IEnumerable<Person> {List<Person>}`. Look at the part in curly braces. The underlying object is `List<Person>`. Why? Who decided it?

Comment: No problem. At this point, I think you are going to have to provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, plus perhaps a screenshot of what you see - because my example does _not_ show what you are describing.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can extract relevant code easily (it is part of a large application). Before that, can you change the definition of `w` in your code above to `IEnumerable<int> w = list.Where(i => i < 1);` and then check what the debugger reports in the Type column of Watch window?

Comment: It would probably be simpler and more instructive for you to try this yourself. Two reasons for writing the minimal example yourself are: it makes it much easier for you to write an unambiguous question, and the process of writing it might lead you to your own answers.

Answer (score 0):

Coming a bit late into the party here :)
Actually Linq's "Where" decides what's going to be the underlying implementation of IEnumerable's GetEnumerator.

Look at the source code:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/918e6a9a278bc66fb191c43d4db4a71e63ffad31/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Where.cs#L59

You'll see that based on the "source" type, the methods return  "*WhereSelect**Array**Iterator*" or "*WhereSelect**List**Iterator*" or a more generic "*WhereSelectEnumerableSelector*".

Each of this objects implement the GetEnumerator over an Array, or a List, so I'm pretty sure that's why you see the underlying object type being one of these on VS inspector.

Hope this helps clarifying.

Answer (score -1):

I have been digging into this myself. I believe the 'underlying type' is an iterator method, not an actual data structure type.

> An iterator method defines how to generate the objects in a sequence
> when requested.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators#enumeration-sources-with-iterator-methods

In my usecase/testing, the iterator is System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator. I don't think this is a collection data type. It is a method that can enumerate IEnumerables.

Here is a snippet:

```
public IEnumerable<Item> ItemsToBuy { get; set; }
```

...

```
    ItemsToBuy = Enumerable.Range(1, rng.Next(1, 20))
        .Select(RandomItem(rng, market))
        .SelectMany(e => e);
```

The property is IEnumerable and .SelectMany returns IEnumerable. So what is the actual collection data structure? I don't think there is one in how I am interpreting 'collection data structure'.

> Also is it safe to cast Adults to List or Array without
> calling ToList() or ToArray()?

Not for me. When attempting to cast ItemsToBuy collection in a foreach loop I get the following runtime exception:

> {"Unable to cast object of type
> 'SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CashMart.Models.Item],CashMart.Models.Item]'
> to type 'CashMart.Models.Item[]'."}

So I could not cast, but I could .ToArray(). I do suspect there is a performance hit as I would think that the IEnumerable would have to 'do things' to make it an array, including memory allocation for the array even if the entities are already in memory.

> However if I place inspect the value of target object, it reveals that
> the actual underlying object is List

This was not my experience and I think it may depend on the IEnumerable source as well as the LinQ provider. If I add a where, the returned iterator is:

> System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator

I am unsure what your _Member source is, but using LinQ-to-Objects, I get an iterator. LinQ-to-Entities must call the database and store the result set in memory somehow and then enumerate on that result. I would doubt that it internally makes it a List, but I don't know much. I suspect instead that _Members may be a List somewhere else in your code thus, even after the .Where, it shows as a List.